# Emacs keybind in mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to make keybind only in the HTML mode.

```
(defun mf-stylesheet ()                                                         
    (interactive)                                                                 
     ;; Insert CSS stylesheet link
    (insert "<link href=\" \" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\">")             
    ;; Go to href=" "
    (backward-char 36)
    )                                                                             

(eval-after-load "html"
    '(define-key html-mode-map (kbd "C-c s") 'mf-stylesheet))
```

No messages are shown when I run emacs but C-c s is not bound.

Comment: is that a typo that the fn is `my-insert-stylesheet` while the reference is only `mf-stylesheet`? It works for me locally when fixing that.

Comment: @MattWhipple that was a typo. The code has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (define-key html-mode-map (kbd "C-c s") 'mf-stylesheet)))
```

Also, consider using [Yasnippet](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet)